# Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Location: (?)

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

Anyone run into this problem and found a sollution ?

For what i am thinking this is clearly not a problem with the project code itself, but a problem of some sort of configuration

i have the following webpack line that generates this error for me.

```
 new AotPlugin({
      exclude: [],
      mainPath: 'main.ts',
      replaceExport: false,
      skipCodeGeneration: !isProd,
      tsConfigPath: root('src/tsconfig.app.json'),
    })
```

if i set skipCodeGeneration to false everything is working just fine

i also have this tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

and the tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Just so that i am clear i don't have any Loacation service and or component module in my app.

Comment: Did you get this error in terminal? What about console of browser?

Comment: i get this error in the browser console, terminal seem to be fine with message compiled succesfully